# Django REST Generic View for related model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a setup similar to this - a Cookbook class, which has multiple Recipes.

I have a

```
class CookbookListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Cookbook.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CookbookSerializer
```

and this handles creating / listing the cookbooks.

I need a `ListCreateView` for the Recipe model but the list must belong to a specific cookbook, in such a way that this url:

`/cookbook/2/recipes`

would return only recipes found in a cookbook with pk of 2.

How can I modify `ListCreateAPIView` to follow this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new route/url:
`/cookbook/<cookbook_pk>/recipes`

And an api view as you want:

```
class RecipeListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer

    def get_cookbook(self):
        queryset = Cookbook.objects.all()
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=self.kwargs['cookbook_pk'])

    def get_queryset(self):
        cookbook = self.get_cookbook()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(cookbook=cookbook)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        cookbook = self.get_cookbook()
        serializer.save(cookbook=cookbook)
```

Use `get_cookbook` whenever you need the cookbook (eg. in `perform_create` method as above)

Answer (score 0):

That's what called a "Detail Route" in DRF.

```
class CookbookListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    ....

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def recipes(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Do what you would do in a function-based view here
```

It will suffice for simple cases but in more complex views using [nested route](https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes) functionality of [DRF-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/) is a better solution.